# How to compare a wstring with a _T("some String")?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compare

I have a function`wstring A2T(const string& str)` to convert `string` to `wstring`. But I cannot get the correct value when I compare the return value with a `const wstring`. For example;

```
wstring strOn = A2T("on");
 if ( strOn == _T("on")) 
 {
     SetItemSwitch(true); 
 }
 else
 {
     SetItemSwitch(false);
 }
```

The `if(strOn == _T("on"))` statement is always false. What is wrong with my code?

This is the `A2T`:

```
std::wstring A2T(const string& str)
{
    if (str.empty()) return std::wstring();
    int sz = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str.c_str(), -1, 0, 0);

    std::wstring res(sz, 0);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], -1, &res[0], sz);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: How is `wstring A2T(const string& str)` implemented?

Comment: using MultiByteToWideChar()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the interpretation (or use of) of the return value from the first call to [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx) - it will return the size required for the buffer including the terminating `NULL` character. When creating the wide string, the count for `NULL` should be removed from the size, the string will add that internally.

In addition, on the second call, use the actual sizes of the strings; this is to avoid the `MultiByteToWideChar` from processing the buffer including any terminating `NULL` characters (their presence is already catered for in the string size calculations). Again, the strings will manage the `NULL` internally.

```
std::wstring A2T(const std::string& str)
{
    if (str.empty())
        return std::wstring();
    int sz = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str.c_str(), -1, 0, 0);

    std::wstring res(sz - 1, 0);
    //                  ^^^ count to "remove" the NULL
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], str.size(), &res[0], res.size());
    //                                       ^^^ use actual sizes
    return res;
}
```

---

Depending on the version of the compiler being used, you could also investigate the use of [`std::basic_string::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) for `res.data()` over the use of `&res[0]`.